# Stochastic processes with the same distribution

Tags: limits, probability-distributions, continuity, metric-spaces, stochastic-processes

We studied the following theorem, but we didn't prove it. Is there anybody who knows a correct proof of it? Our teacher said the $\pi-\lambda$ lemmas are considered when we want to prove it.

The statement is the following: Let $X$ and $Y$ be two continuous stochastic processes. Let's define the following two random vectors: $$\mathbf{X_{t}}\overset{\circ}{=}\left[X_{t_{1}},X_{t_{2}},\ldots,X_{t_{n}}\right]$$ and $$\mathbf{Y_{t}}\overset{\circ}{=}\left[Y_{t_{1}},Y_{t_{2}},\ldots,Y_{t_{n}}\right].$$

If $\mathbf{X}_{\mathbf{t}}$ and $\mathbf{Y}_{\mathbf{t}}$ have the same distribution ($\mathbf{X}_{\mathbf{t}}\overset{d}{=}\mathbf{Y}_{\mathbf{t}}$), then the two processes: $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution on the space of continuous processes as well.

My additional question whether this is only holds for continuous processes or not? Couldn't we extend it to right-sided continuous processes ($\lim_{x\searrow x_{0}}f\left(x\right)=f\left(x_{0}\right)$) with existing left side limit?

Comment: Specify the index set. 'distribution on the space of continuous processes' is  a vague term. State precisely  what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Let's define $\sigma\left(X\right)$ as the natural filtration of $X$ ($\sigma\left(X\right)=\sigma\left(X_{t}:t\geq0\right)$). Every $A\in\sigma\left(X\right)$ set can be expressed as the following form: $A=\left\{ X\in B\right\}$  (which is the same that $A=X^{-1}\left(B\right)$) where $B\in C\left[0,\infty\right)$. ...

Comment: ... So we can introduce a $\mathcal{B}$ $\sigma$-algebra on $C\left[0,\infty\right)$,where $A\in\sigma\left(X\right)\Longleftrightarrow X\in H$, for an appropriate $B\in\mathcal{B}$. On this $\mathcal{B}$ $\sigma$-algebra we can introduce a new probability measure $\mathbf{Q}_{X}$, where $\mathbf{Q}_{X}\left(B\right)=\mathbf{P}\left(X^{-1}\left(B\right)\right)=\mathbf{P}\left(\omega:X\in B\right)$. I say two process:$X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution if $\mathbf{Q}_{X}\left(B\right)=\mathbf{Q}_{Y}\left(B\right)$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$.